# Dot notation in Nunjucks sorting isn't working

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I'm using Eleventy (11ty) with Nunjucks. I have some JSON data that I am trying to sort. The [Jinja documentation says](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#sort) that you can sort by attribute using dot notation, but when I try sorting by `address.city`, nothing happens:

```
{% for item in testData|sort(attribute="address.city") %}
  {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

It *does* work if I sort without dot notation/by a top level field (`name`):

```
{% for item in testData|sort(attribute="name") %}
  {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

My test data (`testData.json`):

```
[
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "address":
    {
      "city": "A?"
    },
    "salary": 2,
    "married": true
  },
  {
    "name": "III",
    "address": {
      "city": "D?"
    },
    "salary": 1,
    "married": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Support for dot notation in `sort` is not yet published. It is already [merged](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/1298).

Comment: Jinja is an implementation of a common syntax in a family of template languages; Nunjucks is another one. The fact that the Jinja implementation has a certain feature doesn’t mean that Nunjucks also has it.

Comment: @lxg — thanks for clarifying. The [Nunjucks templating documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html) says "Nunjucks is essentially a port of jinja2, so you can read their docs if you find anything lacking here." That's what led me to believe that features present in Jinja would also be in Nunjucks.

Comment: I have some [research](https://gist.github.com/ogonkov/fcbff2b84615b0207c8bdc2c2addff95) of filters support in Nunjucks, if you interested.

Comment: Thanks, @LeshaOgonkov! I'm going to bookmark that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as seen in the comments to my question, sorting by dot notation isn't supported  in Nunjucks currently.

What I did in the end, to get what I needed in my Nunjucks template in Eleventy, was to create a [custom filter](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/nunjucks/#filters), inside of `.eleventy.js`, along the lines of:

```
eleventyConfig.addFilter("sortByCity", arr => {
  arr.sort((a, b) => (a.address.city) > (b.address.city) ? 1 : -1);
  return arr;
});
```

Then, in my Nunjucks template:

```
{% for item in testData | sortByCity %}
  {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I know this answer is more 11ty-specific, but I think this could quite possibly work for other environments to extend Nunjucks. Hopefully this will be of help to someone else in the future. [Nunjucks docs about Filters are here](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#filters)

Comment: Nice, i'd consider a more versatile filter by using lodash!